# Tensorflow: sess.run([x]) not working but sess.run([y]) works with the same feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorboard, and I am following the code in [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4)

Below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
LOGDIR = "/tmp/mnist_tutorial/"
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=LOGDIR + "data", one_hot=True)

def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, size_in, size_out]))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_out]))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
        act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return act


def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_in, size_out]))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_out]))
        act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w)+b)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return act

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name='x')
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name='labels')

conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, name='conv1')
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

conv2 = conv_layer(pool1, 32, 64, name='conv2')
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
flattened = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7*7*64, 1024, name='fc1')
logits = fc_layer(fc1, 1024, 10, name='fc2')

with tf.name_scope('xent'):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y))
    tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', xent)

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(xent)

with tf.name_scope('accruacy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar('accruacy', accuracy)

summ = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # writer =tf.summary.FileWriter("tmp/mnist_demo/1")
    # writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    # writer.close()

    for i in range(20):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

        # Occasionally report back the accruacy

        if i%2 == 0:
            [train_accruacy] = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) # works
#             [s, train_accruacy] = sess.run([summ, accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) #error!
            print("step %d, training accruacy %g" % (i, train_accruacy))

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch[0],y:batch[1]})
```

I run into an error when I use this line:

`[s, train_accruacy] = sess.run([summ, accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) #error!`

This is the error message I get:

`You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [?,784]
     [[{{node x}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

which I understand that the tensor which I fed in is not of the correct shape of (x, 784).

However, I don't get why `[train_accruacy] = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) # works`. After all, I'm feeding in the same thing into the same placeholder variables, which are accepting tensors of the same shape.

Unless I am completely mistaken, the first argument of `sess.run([argument], feed_dict=...)` describes the tensor to return. I don't see how that affects the shape of the data I'm feeding in.

Also: this model is supposed to have an error in it.

For those interested, the full code is [here](https://github.com/martinwicke/tf-dev-summit-tensorboard-tutorial/blob/master/mnist.py).

Could it also be that the return datatype is different? `tf.summary.merge_all()` returns a string tensor, but I doubt that's what causing the issue.

I can't seem to find any documentation of this problem online. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: maybe its type mismatch, x iis of tf.float32 and there is Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT what can differ, for example be x64 by default

Comment: But I put my x placeholder as tf.float32 already. What is x64 by default?

Comment: Plus it shouldn't be a type mismatch? I'm feeding in the same input

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question:

`tf.reset_default_graph()` works, added before the `def conv_layer()`.

If one doesn't want to use `tf.reset_default_graph()`:

Turns out I was feeding in 2 tensors in the same session, which tensorflow wouldn't allow.

```
for i in range(20):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch[0],y:batch[1]})
    # Occasionally report back the accruacy

    if i%2 == 0:
        [train_accruacy] = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) # works
#             [s, train_accruacy] = sess.run([summ, accuracy], feed_dict={x:batch[0], y:batch[1]}) #error!
        print("step %d, training accruacy %g" % (i, train_accruacy))
```

The above code **doesn't work.** It turns out that for some reason, the first line code below `i%2` feeds in the tensor `batch[0]` just fine, however, when it comment out that line and replaced it with the second line, it seems like tensorflow doesn't 'flush' out the `x` placeholder variable and as such 2 seperate tensors are  fed into the input (from seperate `sess.run()`) events.

This code works:

```
for i in range(2000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    if i%10 !=0:
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch[0],y:batch[1]})
        # Occasionally report back the accruacy

    if i%10 == 0:
        [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
        print("step %d, training accruacy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
        writer.add_summary(s,i)
```

Here the tensors are fed in separately and everything runs fine.

I'd be glad if anyone could let me know why this is happening, or if this is a bug.